# Multiline prompt in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I need to create multiple line prompt.

```
set /p choice="Press '1' for start host; Press '0' for exit;"
```

Output should be:

```
Press '1' for start host;
Press '0' for exit;
```

How it is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Echo Press '1' for start host;
set /p choice="Press '0' for exit;"
```

is probably simplest

Comment: The first line is just displaying text. The last line is collecting the input.